# How to obtain the public key (not public hash - PKH) using taquito

Tags: taquito, dapps

In order to use the `verifySignature` method in Taquito, I need the public key of the wallet. I can only find the public key hash method - am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Below is how I obtain the wallet public key hash:

```
wallet.requestPermissions({ network: { type: 'hangzhounet' } })
      .then(() => wallet.getPKH());
```

Comment: I found one method that seems to work:

GET https://mainnet.smartpy.io/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/{public_key_hash}/manager_key

Answer (score 1):

Taquito doesn't have such a feature per se, but you can access this piece of information through the `client` property of the `wallet` instance, which contains the same data as the `DappClient` instance of the `@airgap/beacon-sdk` package:

```
const wallet = new BeaconWallet(OPTIONS);
const activeAccount = await wallet.client.getActiveAccount();
const { publicKey } = activeAccount;
```

Answer (score 0):

This requires a RPC query to the node. You can use `RpcClient.getManagerKey()`:

```
import { RpcClient } from '@taquito/rpc';
const rpcClient = new RpcClient('https://ghostnet.ecadinfra.com/');

const pkh = 'tz1a496f48q8idHSEbhAe3dc9vE9sTX3DEJi'; // Replace with the PKH you want to get the public key for
rpcClient.getManagerKey(pkh).then(publicKey => console.log(`Public key for manager with PKH ${pkh}: ${publicKey}`));
```

The doc for this function is:

https://tezostaquito.io/typedoc/classes/_taquito_rpc.rpcclient.html#getmanagerkey